# Can we keep both web client & jsreport server both authentication with identity server 4

Tags: authentication, jsreport

Hi I am trying to implement authentication by identity server 4 (sample:"[jsreport-with-authorization-server-sample](https://github.com/bjrmatos/jsreport-with-authorization-server-sample)"), where I can setup web app client and jsreport server with authentication server. But problem is here we have to remove admin section from :

```
"authentication": { 
   "admin": {
   "username": "admin",
   "password": "password"
}
```

to add

```
"authorizationServer": {
    "tokenValidation": {
    "endpoint": "http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect",
    "usernameField": "username",
    "activeField": "active",
    "scope": {
    "valid": ["jsreport"]
},
"auth": {
     "type": "basic",
     "basic": {
     "clientId": "jsreport",
     "clientSecret": "secret"
    }
   }
  }
 },
 "enabled": true
}
```

Now we can execute report from jsreport server without login. My question is can we keep both client & report server both authentication with identity server 4?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can keep both authorization server auth and normal jsreport login.

you just need to keep the `admin` options of `authentication` config.

with a config like this:

```
{
  ...
  "authentication": {
    "cookieSession": {
      "secret": "<your strong secret>"
    },
    "admin": {
      "username": "admin",
      "password": "password"
    },
    "authorizationServer": {
      "tokenValidation": {
        "endpoint": "http://jsreport-sample.com:5000/connect/introspect",
        "usernameField": "username",
        "activeField": "active",
        "scope": {
          "valid": ["jsreport"]
        },
        "auth": {
          "type": "basic",
          "basic": {
            "clientId": "jsreport",
            "clientSecret": "secret"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "enabled": true
  }
  ...
}
```

you can keep jsreport studio login and also can login from http API calls using token based auth (delegated to authorization server) and normal basic auth (handled by jsreport)

Comment: Hi BJR Matos thanks for the answer, I tried in this way but I found unauthorized for web client request. Not sure if I missed anything or not.

Comment: I have identity server 4 users in database and users can login with their credential. if I use admin for studio then other users get unauthorized from jsreport server. Do I need to add the admin user in identity server 4 also?

Comment: hmm weird, i have not tried a case where admin user is not specified so probably something is missing here. what authorizationServer options do is just delegate the request to the other server and that server should respond with a user that exists in jsreport user entities too, i guess that normal jsreport auth + authorizationServer options is not working correctly when admin is not defined, i will try to setup and test a case for this later. thanks

Comment: I can have any number of identity server users in database, after login how they all will be identified by jsreport server? It seems it can only define admin user which is not defined in identity server.

Comment: Is there any update on this, in the sample we get error: Error while trying to get reports list from jsreport: Unauthorized when click on the button "Get Profile and Access Token for jsreport" button after login by identity server user